# type 'ZTERM' is unknown in BDC in SAP ABAP

Tags: abap

I am trying to implement BDC - Session Method for VA01(Creating Sales order). I am following the steps by watching the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yN_NUZKMdk0 .

```
TYPES : BEGIN OF TY_CSO,
        ZTERM TYPE ZTERM,
        END OF TY_CSO.

DATA : IT_CSO TYPE TABLE OF TY_CSO,
    WA_CSO TYPE TY_CSO.

perform bdc_field using 'VBKD-ZTERM'
                          WA_CSO-ZTERM .
```

The error is `Type ZTERM is unknown`, although SAP knows that ZTERM is in VBKD table. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: The error is **type** ZTERM is not known. Do you have a data element/domain of this type?

Answer (score 0):

VBKD-ZTERM is type DZTERM not ZTERM.  you need to update your data declaration to either:

```
TYPES : BEGIN OF TY_CSO,
    ZTERM TYPE VBKD-ZTERM,
    END OF TY_CSO.
```

or

```
TYPES : BEGIN OF TY_CSO,
    ZTERM TYPE DZTERM,
    END OF TY_CSO.
```

Either one should solve your problem.